# How do I determine the collision normal in an axis aligned bounding box collision?

Tags: collision-detection, geometry, normals, bounding-boxes

I have a 3d moving box and a stationary box.  I can detect collisions ok but now I would like to slide the moving box against the stationary box as a collision response.  For this I need the normal of the face that collides with the moving box.  Does anyone know how I figure this out?  It doesn't seem like the collision test gives me this information.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The collision normal and the normal of the colliding face are different things. The collision normal depends on the subtracted velocities of the colliding objects. Whereas calculating the normal of a face is shown in Valkea's answer. For a proper collision response you will need both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to calculate the normal to a plane (the collided AABB face) you need:

- 3 points of this plane (2 non parallel edges).
- The cross product of two edge vectors of this plane (usually from the same point of origin).

This will produce a vector perpendicular to this plane (but a plane have 2 sides).

---

Here is an example of how to calculate the cross product.

Let A, B, C and D be the four points of your AABB collided side.

```
[B]---(c)
 |     |
[A]---[D]
```

If we use ABC, then the normal to the plane is

```
ADxAB (if we want a normal pointing out of the screen)
ABxAD (if we want a normal pointing inside the screen)
```

*(it's just because our example is facing the screen, if the plane is seen from left side, the fist normal will point right and the second will point left)*

As you can see the order in which you take the points will impact the side the normal will point to. That's why developers usually store their points in a specified order (clockwise or counter-clockwise, but the same for all faces) so they know in which order to use them.

---

See this on more details now:

```
AB = [ Bx-Ax, By-Ay, Bz-Az ]
AD = [ Dx-Ax, Dy-Ay, Dz-Az ]
```

Here is how to get the first normal

```
ADxAB = [ ADx, ADy, ADz ] X  [ ABx, ABy, ABz ]
      = [ (ADy*ABz - ADz*ABy), (ADz*ABx - ADx*ABz), (ADx*ABy - ADy*ABx) ]
```

And here come the second normal pointing to the other side

```
ABxAD = [ ABx, ABy, ABz ] X  [ ADx, ADy, ADz ]
      = [ (ABy*ADz - ABz*ADy), (ABz*ADx - ABx*ADz), (ABx*ADy - ABy*ADx) ]
```

If you replace the ABx, ABy, ABz etc. values with the differences calculated just before (Bx-Ax, By-Ay, Bz-Az etc.) the cross products you will get the normal vectors.

Comment: I have a min and a max. How do I calculate the normal with those